# Defining Flow types for and creating Immutable Records

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, immutable.js, flowtype

I’m trying to get Flow working with Immutable.js Records.

I’m defining my record as:

```
const MyRecord = new Immutable.Record({id: undefined})
```

and then creating records with

```
new MyRecord({id: 1})
```

When I run Flow, I get an error on the `new MyRecord` constructor call that says:

> constructor call Constructor cannot be called on Record

Am I defining the record incorrectly? Or do I need to some how specify the type for the constructor?

I am using flow-bin 0.33.0 and immutable 3.8.0 inside a React Native 0.38.0 project.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you change `new Immutable.Record` to `Immutable.Record` without the `new`?

Comment: You're trying to call a constructor on an object that is already constructed. `Record` is creating a new class not constructing an object. Remove the new keyword from the first statement.

Comment: Ahh yeah that was it. It's alright for me to `export default Immutable.Record({id: undefined})`, right?

Thanks for the help. Resubmit as an "answer" and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Jake done. answer is below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call a constructor on an object that is already constructed. `Record` is creating a new class not constructing an object. Remove the `new` keyword from the first statement and it should work.

Comment: This ends up with a `Callable signature not found in Record` on the objects Record() returns.

Comment: More specifically, if the Record sets the type like `export const DocumentRecord: Immutable.Record<Document> = Immutable.Record({...})` then it fails.